# Make all subclasses conform to a particular protocol

Tags: ios, swift

So, I have implemented a protocol, called ResuableCell

```
protocol ResuableCell{
static func resuableIdentifier()->String}
```

Now, I wish to conform UICollectionViewCell to it, so that all my subsequent UICollectionViewCell will be formed to implement such a method.

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `extension UICollectionViewCell: ResuableCell {}`

Comment: @Scriptable that would mean that all the UICollectionViewCell shares the same function, which produces the same identifier string. What I want is an individual function to produce individual identifier string

Comment: that wouldn't do that because it doesnt define a function or any functionality. it just says that all UICollectionViewCell's must confirm to that protocol. you could also provide default functionality and return the string version of the class name as the identifier.. making it automatically filled and unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reusable protocol and protocol extensions to return the reuseIdentifier value. Then add extension on UICollectionViewCell and confirm the reusableCell protocol so that every UICollectionviewCell subclass will have the reusableIdentifier available.

```
protocol ReusableCell: AnyObject {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension ReusableCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}

extension UICollectionViewCell: ResuableCell {}
```

There is [reusable library](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable) available which does this nicely. You can follow this [blog](http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/generics/2016/01/06/generic-tableviewcells/) on how to implement this feature.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need

Answer (score 0):

extend your custom uiCollectionViewCell with ReusableCell

```
extension CustomCollectionViewCell : ReusableCell { 
}
```

don't forget to assign the delegate